# How to show the original website view in android mobiles?

Tags: android, webview

How to show the original website view in android mobiles?

I have written an application to show the Youtube page in my webview. But when i run it on phone i am getting the mobile view of the website. How can i explicitly show the Webpage as i see in my PC in my Android phone (how can i do it my application)?

Comment: which widget you are using in order to display the website.

Comment: I think i just need a WebView to display the Webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Try launching this url...

http://www.youtube.com/?nomobile=1

Comment: @sen Not sure why it opens moobile view for you. Atleast, its not reproducible on my phone.